# Conditionally convert multiple formats of Date and DateTime string into JavaScript Date Object

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

With this little utility JavaScript function below it can convert a basic Date string into a JavaScript Date object.

The date string can be in multiple formats like this...

```
stringToDate("17/9/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", "/");
stringToDate("9/17/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy", "/");
stringToDate("9-17-2014", "mm-dd-yyyy", "-");
```

What I am hoping to do is expand it to also allow conditionally strings that also have a Time in them `09:12:49` `09:12:49am`, `09:12:49pm`

So my function below where it creates the Date object with this line...

```
var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex], month, dateItems[dayIndex]);
```

would have to instead do something like...

```
var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex], month, dateItems[dayIndex], hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

adding the `hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds` only if they are detected in the original string.

Would such a task be possibble with this code?

```
  // Convert Date String into JS Date Object
  // Can parse multiple Date formats
  // stringToDate("17/9/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", "/");
  // stringToDate("9/17/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy", "/");
  // stringToDate("9-17-2014", "mm-dd-yyyy", "-");
  function stringToDate(d, _format, _delimiter) {
    if((d instanceof Date)){
      return d;
    }
    var formatLowerCase = _format.toLowerCase();
    var formatItems = formatLowerCase.split(_delimiter);
    var dateItems = d.split(_delimiter);
    var monthIndex = formatItems.indexOf("mm");
    var dayIndex = formatItems.indexOf("dd");
    var yearIndex = formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
    var month = parseInt(dateItems[monthIndex]);
    month -= 1;
    var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex], month, dateItems[dayIndex]);
    return formatedDate;
  }
```

---

I am aware of MomentJS, DateJS, DateJS Evolved, and SugarJS but I am trying to do this for a small utility library.

Comment: It sounds like you already have your answer,  have you tried applying it to see what happens?  One issue may be that you now have more than one delimiter to contend with.  You may also need to handle am/pm yourself.  It's possible - sure, but in the end you may find using moment much more convenient.  (Avoid date.js if you can, or use the evolved fork)

Comment: @MattJohnson I realize the "smart" thing to do is simply use MomentJS however I have a small Date library with some pretty specific features to my project that Moment and others dont easily perfomr so it would be really cool if I can add a couple more functions like this to my library in this particular case.  AS for more delimiters to handle, I see that but I think it's pretty safe to assume times will generally has the `:` between them which might help me in this case....continued..

Comment: @MattJohnson ...continued.... I have found many interesting functions on my StackOverflow JS date searches so far! Maybe grabbing first 10 characters and knowing that will always be the Date portion will help too. `if(dateStr > 10){ //assume it has a time portion to attempt parsing )`

Comment: Ok.  Good luck!  not sure how this question is answerable though. :)

Comment: Your month number conversion seems a little verbose, consider: `dateItems[monthIndex] - 1`, since subtraction will convert the string to a number for you, and what you're returning isn't a formatted date, but a Date object so you might want to change the variable name. :-)